# MVC5 Models don't get linked

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I did a Category Model and a product model.
When I scaffold these two I want to have a drop down on my product model with all my categories.

However, when scaffold these two models on my product model I get a Categories ID and it's a int. Not a drop down for my categories.

Category:

```
    public class Category
{
    #region properties
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Category")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You need to enter a category")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

Product:

```
    public class Product
{
    #region properties
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "An Item Name is required")]
    [StringLength(160)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Price is required")]
    [Range(0.01, 999.99, ErrorMessage = "Price must be between 0.01 and 999.99")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public int CatagorieId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Check the following link http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/examining-how-aspnet-mvc-scaffolds-the-dropdownlist-helper

Comment: @Ala Its not an older version. It's mvc5.

Comment: The category in the website says that it is an older version but the concept is common among the older versions and MVC5. Take a look at the content

Comment: is categorieId the foreignkey to Category?

Comment: @Thorarins Yes, it's a fk.

Comment: in that case you need to add attribute [ForeignKey("CategorieId")]  on Category  otherwise it wont know that (I guess u are using EF)

Comment: @Thorarins It should know that, when I add a migration, and i see the migration it says `.ForeignKey("dbo.Categories", t => t.Category_Id)`

Comment: that is in the table ,if you take a look at the database table you would see that you have end up with two columns one category_id , and a CategorieID  the latter is just handles as any other Int property and has no conection to Category class

Comment: @Thorarins So on my CategoryModel I just add [ForeignKey("CategorieId")] and EF will know I refeer my product model to that category model?

Comment: yes, you need to point out the fk id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add FK attribute on Category

```
  using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
  using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

  public class Product
  {

        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "An Item Name is required")]
        [StringLength(160)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Price is required")]
        [Range(0.01, 999.99, ErrorMessage = "Price must be between 0.01 and 999.99")]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        public int CatagorieId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CatagorieId")]
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: There was an error running the selected Code Generator:
'Unable to retrieve mdtadata for 'Product.Models.Product' the foreginKeyAttribute on property 'Catagory' on type'Product.Models.Product is not valid.

Comment: shouldn't be any problem, but you need to add ef and maybe the context and so on...

Comment: I never been needing to do this before, I assum that is because I just call my ID on category Id for ID and not CategoryID so EF gets confused..

Comment: yes, it might also be that it was misspelled , catagorieId  :)